# U uniform on [-1,1] - Find density of U^2

Tags: probability-distributions, proof-verification

Let $U$ be uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$. Find the denstiy of $U^2$.

I would start with $F_{U^2}(u)$=$P(U^2\le u)$=$P(-\sqrt{u}\le U\le\sqrt{u})$ for $u\ge 0$. Since it is uniformly distributed it follows that $F_{U^2}(u)$=$\sqrt{u}+\sqrt{u}$=$2\sqrt{u}$.

Thus $f_{U^2}(u)$=$(2\sqrt{u})'$=$1 \over{\sqrt{u}}$. for $0 \le u\le \infty$

Is it correct? I would appreciate some help or hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost correct. There are some small mistakes. First note that $U$ is uniformly distributed over an intervall of length 2, hence 
$$ \def\P{\mathbf P}\P(-\sqrt u \le U \le \sqrt u) = \color{red}{\frac 12} \cdot 2 \sqrt u = \sqrt u $$
Moreover, this only holds for $u \in [0,1]$ (as $U^2 \le 1$ a. s.), for $u \ge 1$ we have $F_{U^2}(u) = 1$.
Hence
$$ f_{U^2}(u) = \frac 1{2\sqrt u}, \qquad u \in (0,1] $$
and $f_{U^2}(u) = 0$ for $u \not\in (0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate your help!